# Can we say that amplitude of light scattered by air molecules is inversely proportional to the square of wavelength of incident light?

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering, intensity

As per Rayleigh's criteria of scattering of light by air molecules  the intensity of scattered light is inversely proportional to the forth power of wavelength.
AND WE ALSO SAY :
Intensity of a wave is proportional to square of its amplitude.
Now my doubt is that can I combine these two statements to say that amplitude of scattered light is inversely proportional to square of wavelength of incident light?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, amplitude of electric field of the Rayleigh scattering radiation from a molecule/air density fluctuation is proportional to square of frequency, and thus to inverse wavelength squared.